# Parse json files with comments? (keybindings.json)

Tags: vscode-extensions, json5

Does VSCode provides any means to parse json files with comments without using external library?

I'm trying get list of keybindings for the extension and need to parse `keybindings.json` file, which contains comments

I'm currently using [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) package, but would like to get rid of it:

```
//get keybindings
const keybindings = new Promise(resolve => {
  //default keybindings
  const data = require("../package.json").contributes.keybindings.reduce((a,b)=>(a[b.command]=b.key,a),{});
  const parse = list => {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].command in data)
        data[list[i].command] = list[i].key;
    }
    for(let i in data) {
      //capitalize first letter
      data[i] = data[i].replace(/\w+/g, w => (w.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()) + w.substring(1));
      //add spaces around "+"
      // data[i] = data[i].replace(/\+/g, " $& ");
    }

    Object.assign(keybindings, data);
    resolve(data);
  };
  const path = {
    windows: process.env.APPDATA + "/Code",
    macos: process.env.HOME + "/Library/Application Support/Code",
    linux: process.env.HOME + "/config/Code"
  }[{
    aix: "linux",
    darwin: "macos",
    freebsd: "linux",
    linux: "linux",
    openbsd: "linux",
    sunos: "linux",
    win32: "windows"
  }[process.platform]||"windows"];
  const file = ((process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE ? process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data/User/" : path) + "/User/keybindings.json")
    .replace(/\//g, process.platform == "win32" ? "\\" : "/");

  //read file
  workspace.openTextDocument(file).then(doc => {
    //we can't use JSON.parse() because file may contain comments
    const JSON5 = require("json5").default;
    parse(JSON5.parse(doc.getText()));
  }).catch(er => {
    parse([]);
  });
});
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support comments. However, YAML does, and is mostly a superset of JSON, so there's a good chance if you can parse YAML, it will work on a JSON file. YAML comments start with "#" instead of "//".

Comment: Sounds like an external library...

Comment: I think you are stuck with an external library.  There is also the `jsonc-parser` written by a vscode team member which works well on keybindings (I use it in a completionProvider to provide available keys and args).

Comment: @Mark, yes, that's the library VSCode is using. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162434#issuecomment-1263546283

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the JSON5 library? As json5.org's home page points out: `"JSON5 was started in 2012, and as of 2022, now gets >65M downloads/week, ranks in the top 0.1% of the most depended-upon packages on npm, and has been adopted by major projects like Chromium, Next.js, Babel, Retool, WebStorm, and more. It's also natively supported on Apple platforms like MacOS and iOS."`

Comment: @Inigo it's not just JSON5 I don't want to use, but external packages all together if I could help it. But since there is no other way but to use external library, then I'd pick whichever is the smallest/fastest that does one job: read text file and convert its content into an object.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the fact above that you found a way to use the library VSCode uses. Otherwise I was gonna say rolling your own isn't gonna be any smaller unless you know the precise subset of JSON5 VSCode assumes.